# How do I bind underscore table/column names automatically using Dapper-Extensions?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper, dapper-extensions

I am naming my MYSQL tables and columns using underscore characters:

`this_is_a_table` should map to: `ThisIsATable`

`this_is_a_column` should map to: `ThisIsAColumn`

Dapper can handle this mapping if i set:

```cs
DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
```

Is there any way to enable this in Dapper-Extensions so that it maps undescore automatically?

Comment: Rewrote title to form a question (more readable in search-results) and some code-formatting

Comment: That is too bad that the extension doesn't handle the mapping like in the parent namespace, because `DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;` works so well.  This puts a kink in the generic repository I'm building for a project.  I believe the table name mapping works fine still if you decorate the class with `[Table("this_is_a_table")]`.

Comment: @secretwep Thats how i solve it today when creating a generic repo. But as you said MatchNamesWithUnderscores works so well.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward, you just need to create a [custom mapping](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/AutoClassMapper). Here is an example:

**Create table:**

```
create table hello_world
(
    Id int not null,
    Value_Column varchar(max)
)
```

**Test:**

```
public class World
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class WorldCustomMapper : ClassMapper<World>
{
    public WorldCustomMapper()
    {
        base.Table("hello_world");
        Map(f => f.Id).Column("Id");
        Map(f => f.Value).Column("Value_Column");
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMappping()
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=mydb");
        conn.Open();

        var record = new World
        {
            Id = 1,
            Value = "Hi"
        };

        conn.Insert(record);

        var result = conn.Get<World>(1);

        Assert.That(result.Value, Is.EqualTo("Hi"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not mention it in main post, but i want to be able to solve this mapping automatic for all entities. And only use the class mapper in special cases. Updated my post.

Comment: I'm not aware of such feature. By default, your "POCO property names should match each column name in the table," else, custom mapping.